# Program which can produce class diagrams directly from code

Tags: c#, import, uml, documentation-generation, class-diagram

I have a somewhat large C# project which I am starting to lose overview of. I was wondering if there was some software out there which could graphically represent my classes, which calls what, and so forth.

I have tried googling around a little, but only found old software and Visual Studio extensions which did not enable for a direct import to output function.

Suggestions welcome :-)

Regards,
John

Comment: You may have seen this, as I just found it by Googling, but it claims to do something along the lines of what you need : http://nclass.sourceforge.net/downloads.html

Comment: How about Visual Studio built-in diagram file type?

Comment: You dont need any special extension...Check this.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779842/auto-generate-class-diagrams-from-solution)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the built-in "class diagram" file type of Visual Studio.

Add a new class diagram to your project :

```
Add -> New Item -> Class diagram
```

Then drag and drop your classes to the diagram files:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2015 for dnx (xproj) projects - "Class diagrams are not supported by this project type" :(

Comment: Havnt known about this one. Dude, I can even do changes inside the class diagram. How cool is that :D. Upvoted! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Doxygen](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/README.md#doxygen) will generate beautiful hypertext diagrams from source code even for large projects. It uses graphviz library to draw the diagrams and provides an html help as an output. It works well for C-like languages.

Comment: the link `Tools for generating UML class diagram from C# source or dll` in your post is broken.

Comment: the link provided is broken. please update it else remove it. So that it will not guide others with broken link.